# Google Play Console Exception message Issue

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, stack-trace

In Google Play Console in the "ANRs & crashes" section my stack traces are missing the message of the exception.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **MESSAGE SHOULD BE HERE!**
     at com.foo....`

Is there a way to get the exception message?

Comment: Can't you click on that message?

Comment: Looks like your app/library is throwing this exception explicitly.